# Is right pass hsahMap to repository mvvm android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mvvm

Hi is right pass HashMap to functions in repository

```
void sendComment(HashMap<String, String> data){
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(). getRefrence().setValue(data);
}
```

And in viewmodel i create HashMap var and add key,value to it like

```
HashMap<String, String> data=new HashMap<>();
data.add("commentText","any text");
data.add("senderId","any text");
data.add("postId","any text");
repo.sendComment(data);
```

Is that true or should i add arguments senderId,postId,commentText
In function in repository
Like

```
void sendComment(String postId,String senderId){
//Add to database code
}
```

Comment: Matter of opinion, but that’s not how you should do it in a strongly typed language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you can use SparseArray instead of HashMap . because SparseArray is intended to be more memory-efficient than a HashMap, because it avoids auto-boxing keys and its data structure doesn't rely on an extra entry object for each mapping
depends on your task .

```
SparseArray<Int>().set(key , value)
```

you can use the repository for change any object(data) to save in DB or send to the server and change any object(data) to pass to ui and viewModel .

Comment: Ok pass SparseArray or objects i will insert to SparseArray
For example if i will insert to SparseArray key a1 and key a2 pass to repository SparseArray or pass a1,a2

Comment: There are 2 scenarios
First:
  You want to send objects E1 and E2 to the server or save them in the database. Both must be sent to the repository.
Second :
One of them is needed to send to the server or save in the database. Only one of them is sent to the repository.
In fact, if you want to change your values, to prepare it for sending to the server or storing in the database, this change must be done in the repository.

Comment: I mean sir if i want to upload a1,a2 to server with mvvm pattern i maked function in repository to upload to server know what is correct way
1- pass map to it and map has a a1,a2
2-pass a1,a2 directly as a arguments

Comment: you working with map in viewModel so better way is pass the map to it and then convert HashMap to anything you want for sending to server .
way 1 is better :)

Comment: Ok thanks sir..